# Woocommerce Membership API - get restricted content

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-memberships

I am integrating woocommerce memberships into my application using REST API. (https://skyverge.github.io/woocommerce-memberships-rest-api-docs)

How do I get access to restrict content details through API call ?

https://skyverge.github.io/woocommerce-memberships-rest-api-docs/#the-membership-plan

Above API has details of access_product_ids but nothing related to restricted content.

[image]

Comment: If the plugin doesn't provide the field, you can create a custom endpoint. And, for your information, developers might omit some useful information in their documentation. So I recommend you read the plugin code because the code is the best documentation.

Comment: And if you are not familiar with WordPress code or failed to find the solution after the code review, contact me directly so that I can help you in a more detailed way.